# 'db is undefined' problem with firebase integration in JS

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am doing a small contact form on my personal website. I have a problem with integration of firebase database with form. I read the documentation and watched some YT tutorials and I cannot find the mistake. Could you please take a look? I get a 'db is undefined' error in console.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "sampleValue",
      authDomain: "sampleValue",
      databaseURL: "sampleValue",
      projectId: "sampleValue",
      storageBucket: "sampleValue",
      messagingSenderId: "sampleValue",
      appId: "sampleValue",
      measurementId: "sampleValue"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  let db = firebase.firestore;

  function submitForm() {
    // e.preventDefault();

    let nameEl = document.getElementById("InputName");
    let emailEl = document.getElementById("InputEmail");
    let subjectEl = document.getElementById("InputSubject");
    let messageEl = document.getElementById("InputMessage");

    let nameValue = nameEl.value;
    let emailValue = emailEl.value;
    let subjectValue = subjectEl.value;
    let messageValue = messageEl.value;

    db.collection("contact").doc().set({
        name: nameValue,
        email: emailValue,
        subject: subjectValue,
        message: messageValue
      })
      .then(function() {
        alert("dataSaved");
      })
      .catch(function() {
        alert("error");
      });
  }
  document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", submitForm());
};
```

**Edit**
I have managed to solve the problem thanks to fellow users @Kevin Peña and @Phix help by:
putting the missing firebase-firestore.js script in index.html

```
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.12.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

I had realized that settings in my DB disallowed me to push anything from my form so I have changed the rules to

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be firebase.firestore(), and the event listener function shouldn't have the parenthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding a bit on Phix's comment. Right here:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let db = firebase.firestore; // <- here
```

It should be

```
let db = firebase.firestore()
```

You can find this on the [Guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize) and on the [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore).

Also, here:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", submitForm() /* <-over here */);
```

You should not call the function, instead pass it to addEventListener (i.e. just its name)

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", submitForm);
```

Otherwise the form will be submitted empty when the page loads. And nothing will happen on button click.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! After implementing this changes I get the following error "TypeError: firebase.firestore is not a function".

Comment: Make sure that you are properly [including the scripts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment) for both `firebase-app` and `firebase-firestore`